# How to start Activity using instance of it?

Tags: android, android-activity

I used this code to start a activity but throw a NullPointer and illegalState exceptions.this is the code.

```
String test="test";
DownloadActivity downloadAct=new DownloadActivity(test);
Intent intent=new Intent(this,DownloadActivity.class);
downloadAct.startActivity(intent);
```

Is this possible?And i also tried with

```
downloadAct.onCreate();
```

but it need to pass Bundle and i passed

```
new Bundle();
```

it throw null pointer exception,So how can i use DownloadActivity constructers to set its data and start the activity?

Comment: sorry this is not possible

Comment: That means only way is using intent or Bundle?

Comment: What are you want to achieve man??? You can not use Android Activity as like Java class Object. To start an Activity `Intent intent = new Intent(this,DownloadActivity.class);
downloadAct.startActivity(intent);` these code lines are necesarry..

Comment: Why do you need to use a constuctor? to pass data?

Comment: I want to send custom objects to a activity?How can i do that

Answer (score 1):

try this way

```
Intent intent=new Intent(this,DownloadActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

`onCreate()` will called by android os automatically

Answer (score 1):

Try specifying the Activity in the Manifest.

Answer (score 0):

Did your tryed using this.StartActivity(Intent)?

Answer (score 0):

In order to call an Activity with an explicit Intent you have to use this.startActivity(intent) and not secondActivity.startActivity(intent).

Try this code :

```
String test = "test";
Intent intent = new Intent(this,DownloadActivity.class);
i.putString(test);
startActivity(intent);
```